# Camera controls windows vs linux using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have a camera, DMK37BUX287 from the imaging source. I created an app that uses opencv to change various settings on it in real time. On windows, where I first developed using DirectShow api, I was able to change any settings, including the height and width while the camera was running. For example,

```
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 2000)
```

I now have transferred my code to a linux PC which is much faster. Everything still works with the app but now I cannot change the resolution of the camera. If I try to change the height/width, the camera will freeze and cap.read() fails.

I believe the api that is being used is v4l2 and here is the controls I am able to control using v4l-ctl

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -l
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=0 max=4095 step=1 default=240 value=100
                           gain 0x00980913 (int)    : min=0 max=480 step=1 default=0 value=337
                  exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3
              exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=1 max=300000 step=1 default=3 value=6 flags=inactive
               exposure_time_us 0x0199e201 (int)    : min=1 max=30000000 step=1 default=333 value=625
                   auto_shutter 0x0199e202 (bool)   : default=1 value=1
        auto_exposure_reference 0x0199e203 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128
                      gain_auto 0x0199e205 (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                   trigger_mode 0x0199e208 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
               software_trigger 0x0199e209 (button) : flags=write-only
                  strobe_enable 0x0199e211 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                strobe_polarity 0x0199e212 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
               strobe_operation 0x0199e213 (menu)   : min=0 max=1 default=1 value=1
                strobe_duration 0x0199e214 (int)    : min=0 max=32767 step=1 default=100 value=100
                   strobe_delay 0x0199e215 (int)    : min=0 max=32767 step=1 default=0 value=0
                          gpout 0x0199e216 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                           gpin 0x0199e217 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                   roi_offset_x 0x0199e218 (int)    : min=0 max=464 step=2 default=0 value=232
                   roi_offset_y 0x0199e219 (int)    : min=0 max=536 step=2 default=0 value=268
                roi_auto_center 0x0199e220 (bool)   : default=1 value=1
               trigger_polarity 0x0199e234 (menu)   : min=0 max=1 default=0 value=0
          trigger_exposure_mode 0x0199e236 (menu)   : min=0 max=1 default=0 value=0
     auto_functions_roi_control 0x0199e241 (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                flip_horizontal 0x0199e251 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                  flip_vertical 0x0199e252 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
            highlight_reduction 0x0199e253 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
 exposure_auto_upper_limit_auto 0x0199e254 (bool)   : default=1 value=1
   exposure_auto_lower_limit_us 0x0199e255 (int)    : min=1 max=1000000 step=1 default=333 value=1
   exposure_auto_upper_limit_us 0x0199e256 (int)    : min=1 max=1000000 step=1 default=333 value=1663
         override_scanning_mode 0x0199e257 (int)    : min=1 max=16 step=1 default=1 value=1
      auto_functions_roi_preset 0x0199e258 (menu)   : min=0 max=1 default=1 value=1
          gain_auto_lower_limit 0x0199e259 (int)    : min=0 max=480 step=1 default=0 value=0
          gain_auto_upper_limit 0x0199e260 (int)    : min=0 max=480 step=1 default=480 value=480
   trigger_global_reset_release 0x0199e261 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
           imx_low_latency_mode 0x0199e262 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
         scanning_mode_selector 0x0199e263 (int)    : min=1 max=16 step=1 default=1 value=1
       scanning_mode_identifier 0x0199e264 (int)    : min=1 max=1 step=1 default=1 value=1 flags=read-only
 scanning_mode_scale_horizontal 0x0199e265 (int)    : min=1 max=1 step=1 default=1 value=1 flags=read-only
   scanning_mode_scale_vertical 0x0199e266 (int)    : min=1 max=1 step=1 default=1 value=1 flags=read-only
        scanning_mode_binning_h 0x0199e267 (int)    : min=1 max=1 step=1 default=1 value=1 flags=read-only
        scanning_mode_binning_v 0x0199e268 (int)    : min=1 max=1 step=1 default=1 value=1 flags=read-only
       scanning_mode_skipping_h 0x0199e269 (int)    : min=1 max=1 step=1 default=1 value=1 flags=read-only
       scanning_mode_skipping_v 0x0199e270 (int)    : min=1 max=1 step=1 default=1 value=1 flags=read-only
            scanning_mode_flags 0x0199e271 (int)    : min=0 max=0 step=0 default=0 value=0 flags=read-only
            trigger_delay_100ns 0x0199e272 (int)    : min=0 max=100000 step=1 default=0 value=31
```

You will notice the absence of the height/width. When I use the tcam-capture software provided by the imaging source, I am able to change the resolution using that app. I have no idea what else I can try, any help?

Comment: I strongly recommend to use the manufacturer's SDK ditectly for such kind of cameras. Otherwise try to find out whether other applications that rely on V4L2 work with the camera and can change the resolution. If that's not the case it's probably a problem in the driver. If it does work with other V4L2 applications it's more likely an opencv problem. Think about using the manufacturer's support!!

Comment: As v4l-ctl does not list the resolution, best contact the manufacturer, whether you are using the right camera driver!

Comment: @genbio. This is for pc cv2.CAP_DSHOW. This is for linux cv2.CAP_V4L2